# How to get the address of a latitude and longitude in an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I am getting latitude and longitude using CLLocation.  I want to know how I can get the address by using this latitude and longitude.  Please help me.

Comment: can we use Google reverse geo coding api for that ? How to integrate it with iphone sdk

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858872/address-of-location , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551475/get-place-location , among others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `MKReverseGeocoder` class for that purpose, which uses google reverse geocoding facilities.

**Update:** `MKReverseGeocoder` class is deprecated in iOS 5, you should use CLGeocoder class from Core Location framework instead. It provides functions for both forward and reverse geocoding - check [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details

Comment: This class is deprecated in iOS5 :S.