# Getting Location Address from latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkreversegeocoder

I am developing an application in which I have to show the address that of the given latitude and longitude.
I have latitude and longitude but I dont know how to get my address from that latitude and longitude.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the address of a latitude and longitude in an iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063717/how-to-get-the-address-of-a-latitude-and-longitude-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done something very similar to this recently. With the coordinates you can use MKReverseGeocoder to get the address.

when you find the coordinates,

```
    self.reverseGeocoder =[[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate]autorelease];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate=self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
```

//called when reverseGeocoder was successfully able to retreive address

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
    NSString *street=[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
    //get the different address components
}
```

//called when reverseGeocoder was unable to retreive address

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
```

Hope this helps