# Get address and place name using latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode

Hi i m developing an application in which i am getting longitude and latitude of a nearby place of user  using google api.

Now in my application there is a label that show address of that nearby place but how i can get that address and name of place at that longitude and latitude.

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting (there are different APIs for iOS5) ?

Comment: Also, I noticed you taged C#, are you developing this using a cross platform framework, like MonoTouch for instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the address of a latitude and longitude in an iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063717/how-to-get-the-address-of-a-latitude-and-longitude-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MapKit framework? It comes with a class MKReverseGeocoder for exactly that purpose.

Comment: This class is deprecated in iOS5 :S.